# Concurrent / parallel database queries using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, concurrency, parallel-processing, gpars

How do I implement concurrent / parallel database queries using Groovy?

I want to count the number of rows in all tables from a database (`select count(*) from $TABLE`), and write the counts to separate files.

A few of the tables have millions of rows, which take a few minutes to count, and many tables have no rows.  I'm hoping to teach Groovy to separate each count request, wait for the result, grab the next table in the list, and so on.  I am adding this functionality to an existing Groovy script that is solid and works.

Here is what I have so far:

```
retrieve_table_count_list = { objParams ->

    aryTables = objParams.table_list

    objDB2DBRS = [:]
    objDB2DBRS["database_jdbc_url"] = get_config_setting(setting: "DB2DatabaseURL").toString()

    strReturnSQL = ""

    GParsPool.withPool(10) { pool ->
        currentPool = pool
        aryTables.eachWithIndexParallel { objTable, intTable ->

            intNumTables = aryTables.size()
            strTableName = objTable.table_name

            strSQL="select count(*) as \"row_count\" from ${strTableName}"

            aryRowCount = { db_commands(query: strSQL, params: objDB2DBRS) }
            objFastRowCount = aryRowCount.async()
            objResultRowCount = objFastRowCount()

            intRowCount = aryRowCount[0]["row_count"]

            strReturnSQL += "update tmp_TableCount set row_count=${intRowCount} where table_name='${strTableName}';\n"
        }
    }
    return strReturnSQL
}
```

`

The above code is paired down to the essentials.  The original code includes a username and password (which is the only difference) returns this error:

```
Retrieving row counts from DB2
TABLE_NAME: select count(*) as "row_count" from TABLE_NAME: Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 1500.retrieve-accurate-row-counts-db2-concurrent.async() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), asType(java.lang.Class), run(), run(), find()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 1500.retrieve-accurate-row-counts-db2-concurrent.async() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), asType(java.lang.Class), run(), run(), find()
        at 1500.retrieve-accurate-row-counts-db2-concurrent$_run_closure2_closure3_closure4.doCall(1500.retrieve-accurate-row-counts-db2-concurrent.groovy:79)
        at groovyx.gpars.pa.GParsPoolUtilHelper$_eachWithIndex_closure9.doCall(GParsPoolUtilHelper.groovy:182)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.op(Unknown Source)
        at extra166y.AbstractParallelAnyArray$OOMPap.leafTransfer(AbstractParallelAnyArray.java:2249)
        at extra166y.PAS$FJOMap.atLeaf(PAS.java:228)
        at extra166y.PAS$FJBase.compute(PAS.java:78)
        at jsr166y.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:148)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:305)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:575)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:755)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:617)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:369)
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: I've gotten different errors with different approaches I've tried.  I've mostly gotten errors like "`the database connection is closed`".  I'll post a more specific error message asap.

Comment: The code you post is not complete. Where is defined `db_commands` ?

Comment: `db_commands` is a custom closure which I wrote that accepts two parameters: a SQL command, like `select count(*) from table_name`, and connection parameters, like the URL, username and password.  It can also handle DML commands.  In this case, when I give it a SQL `select` command, it returns the results of the query in column/value form.  `db_commands` is my database command wrapper code, which simplifies retrieving results from and updating my database.  I chose not to include it (200+ lines) because it is pretty battle-tested code and I don't believe it is part of my problem.

Comment: Okay! And where is line 79 in your script? The only idea I have with the script I see is the fact you never use "def" to define your properties. They are maybe defined before, but if you don't use "def", then you define a global variable in the script. Theses variables will be shared by all the threads or execution. Moreover, `intRowCount` should probably be `objResultRowCount.get().get(0)["row_count"]`

Comment: Jeremie: Thanks for explaining about "def".  I didn't realize that.  `db_commands` is battle-tested, but apparently not for parallel operations.    It's starting to look like defining variables as global in `db_commands` is my problem, because I'm making a lot of good progress now.  It's not quite fixed yet, but it's closer.  To other SO users, if this turns out to be the problem, should I mark Jeremie's comment above as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems.  Jeremie B's answer helped, but there were other problems.  I'm unsure who to award an answer.  Any input is welcome!

```
// PROBLEM #1:
// db_commands was calling another closure to decrypt a password,
// but the decryption library was not thread safe
// solved by wrapping decryption in a "waiting loop:"
DECRYPT_AVAILABLE = true
// decrypt string
decrypt = { def objParams ->
    // if we're already decrypting a string, wait a short time, then test again
    while (DECRYPT_AVAILABLE == false) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    DECRYPT_AVAILABLE = false
    // ... decrypt text ...
    DECRYPT_AVAILABLE = true
    return decryptedText;
}

def count_table_rows = { def objParams ->
    def strTableName = objParams.table_name
    def objMSSQLDBRS = objParams.params
    def intTotal = objParams.total

    def String strSQL
    def boolean bolCountError
    def int intRowCount
    def String strRowCount
    def String strToLog
    def objRowCount
    def aryRowCount
    def strReturnSQL

    strSQL = "select count(*) as \"row_count\" from ${strTableName}"
    objRowCount = db_commands(query: strSQL, params: objMSSQLDBRS)

    if (objRowCount.containsKey("error") && objRowCount["error"] == true) {
        w(string: "ERROR on SQL: " + strSQL, style: "error");
        w(string: objRowCount["error_message"].toString(), style: "error");
        System.exit(0)
    }

    aryRowCount = objRowCount["data"]
    intRowCount = aryRowCount[0]["row_count"]

    strReturnSQL = "update tmp_TableCounts set row_count=${intRowCount} where table_name='${strTableName}';\n"

    return strReturnSQL
}

def count_all_table_rows = {
    def objPGDBRS = [:]
    def objMSSQLDBRS = [:]
    def strReturn
    objPGDBRS["database_jdbc_url"] = get_config_setting(setting: "PGDatabaseURL").toString()
    def strPGSchema = get_config_setting(setting: "PGDatabaseSchema").toString()

    def strSQL="select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='${strPGSchema}' order by tablename"

    // PROBLEM #2:
    // db_commands can't have any variables defined within the closure that are accessible outside the closure
    // (iow, all variables must be locally scoped)

    def objResults = db_commands(query: strSQL, params: objPGDBRS);

    if (objResults["error"] == true) {
        w(string: "ERROR on SQL: " + strSQL, style: "error");
        w(string: objResults["error_message"].toString(), style: "error");
        System.exit(0)
    }

    def aryTables = objResults["data"].table_name
    def strMSSQLSchema

    objMSSQLDBRS["database_jdbc_url"] = get_config_setting(setting: "MSSQLDatabaseURL").toString()

    GParsPool.withPool() {
        aryTables.eachParallel { def strTableName ->
            strReturn = count_table_rows(table_name: strTableName, params: objMSSQLDBRS, total: aryTables.size())
            strCommands += "$strReturn"
        }
    }

}
```